# Can I add to a vector using placement new

Tags: c++, performance, vector, constructor, placement-new

I have a vector of MyClass, where MyClass is a large class.  When I do:

```
vector<MyClass> vec;
vec.push_back(MyClass(a,b,c));
```

this seems quite inefficient, as a temporary MyClass is created, copied into the vector, then destructed.

Is there some way to use placement new to create the class directly inside the vector in the first place? I can't do it like this:

```
vector<MyClass> vec;
vec.resize(1);
new(&vec.data[0]) MyClass(a,b,c);
```

because vec.resize(1) calls the MyClass constructor.  Is there some way to resize a vector without it calling constructors for all the new items, or is it possible to construct MyClass directly into the vector in the next available place?

Comment: You are looking for `emplace_back`, as in `vec.emplace_back(a, b, c);`

Comment: While the existing answer is correct, you should also implement a move constructor in `MyClass` if it's expensive to copy.  Keep in mind that `std::vector` will have to copy (or move, if available) its elements as it grows.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Maybe, but one must also consider whether making a type cheap to move might make it more expensive to use otherwise (e.g. extra dynamic allocations, indirection on access, etc.)

Comment: @MilesBudnek - In this case I know ahead of time how many elements I need to add, so I can reserve enough space that it's guaranteed not to grow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can use `emplace_back` to build the object in place:

```
vec.emplace_back(a,b,c);
```